# How does C handle non-booleans in an if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, types, pic, mplab-c18

I sometimes see this in a C program (I'm using the C18 compiler):

```
unsigned char someValue = getSomeDataFromSomewhere();
if (someValue) {
    doStuff();
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

I know what happens when you give an `if` loop a boolean (`unsigned` in the C18 compiler), but what happens when you put a non-boolean in?

My guess: it does `doStuff()` when the value isn't zero, and `doOtherStuff()` when the value is zero. But I don't know this, so I'd like to get some reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your guess is right:

from §6.8.4.1 of WG14/N1256

> the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0

Answer (score 7):

Simply put -- if it is non-zero, it is true. If it is zero, it is false.